# Trouble sorting an decimal array with bubblesort. c#

Tags: c#

```
public void BubbleSortArray( int[] numbers )
{
    bool swap;
    int temp;

    do
    {
        swap = false;

        for(int index = 0; index < (numbers.Length - 1); index++)
        {
            if(numbers[index] > numbers[index+1]) //if first number is greater then second then swap
            {
                //swap

                temp = numbers[index];
                numbers[index] = numbers[index + 1];
                numbers[index + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }

    } while (swap == true);
}
```

Okay So I have gotten my bubble sort to work with int numbers but how do I get this code to work with decimals, any help would be appreciated

Comment: by changing your `int[]` to `decimal[]` arguments and your `int temp` to `decimal temp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't you just need to change your `int[]` input to `decimal[]` input?

```
public void BubbleSortArray( decimal[] numbers ) //change here
{
    bool swap;
    decimal temp; //change this too

    do
    {
        swap = false;

        for(int index = 0; index < (numbers.Length - 1); index++)
        {
            if(numbers[index] > numbers[index+1]) //if first number is greater then second then swap
            {
                //swap

                temp = numbers[index];
                numbers[index] = numbers[index + 1];
                numbers[index + 1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }

    } while (swap == true);
}
```

Furthermore, C# supports method overloading. So both methods (the method with `int[]` argument and the method with `decimal[]` argument) can live side by side.

```
public void BubbleSortArray( int[] numbers ){
    ....
}

public void BubbleSortArray( decimal[] numbers ){
    ....
}
```

Comment: This is how I call it 
`code  int[] numbers = new int[1022];
        Decimal[] numbers2 = new decimal[1022];
        Assignment2 obj = new Assignment2(); `

`code  obj.BubbleSortArrayDecimal(numbers2);
        Console.Write("Sorted: ");
        obj.DisplayArray(numbers2);
        Console.Read();` 

it comes out saying error cannot convert from decimal to int

Comment: @AStrugglinStudent probably because you are very new to C#?

Comment: @AStrugglinStudent you mean you want to print the sorted array?

Comment: sorry about that, still getting used to stack overflow

Comment: okay found the issue `code  public void DisplayArrayDecimal(decimal[] numbers)
    {
        for (decimal index = 0; index < numbers.Length; index++)
            
        {

            Console.WriteLine("{0}", numbers[index]);
        }
    } ` it says i need a cast to convert decimal to int, what cast do i use?

Comment: @AStrugglinStudent yep, no problem ;)

Comment: @AStrugglinStudent nevertheless, just to answer your small issue here in the comment, I will just do it: try to use `numbers[index].ToString()` to print your result out: `Console.WriteLine(numbers[index].ToString());`